# Why is admin-ajax.php being called so many times

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, admin-ajax

On my WooCommerce site, can anyone tell me why admin-ajax.php is being called so many times, because it's killing my site load times.

I read about the admin-ajax/heartbeat api issue and tried disabling that, but it didn't help.

Here is a graphic of the site load:
https://www.ashlynnpress.com/imgs/pageload.png

Comment: it's because you are logged in.. it will try to see your logged in session... logout and try again..

Comment: Do you mean logged into my Wordpress admin? I'm pretty sure I'm not. I'm actually at work at the moment haven't logged into my site since last night.

Comment: I just loaded up your site and I don't have any admin-ajax calls loaded on my network tab. Also of note; you're using w3total cache. I can't know this, but you may have caching disabled for administrative logins (which means you'd be logged in even on your work machine). The easiest way to know would be to go to `/wp-admin` and see if you are asked to login. If you're not then you're already logged in and that's why you see the admin-ajax calls.

Comment: Oooh... i lied. i had filters on. I see two calls to admin-ajax when not logged in. Looks like wordfence.

Comment: Hmm. Okay, I thought that might be the culprit. Let me tinker with it for a few. Thanks so much. I'll repost findings.

Comment: Well, getting rid of the Wordfence made a huge difference. I really need the other plugins I have running. Here is an updated pageload graphic (https://www.ashlynnpress.com/imgs/pageload2.png) You can obviously see the two calls for the admin-ajax.php file.

Comment: try disabling Woo commerce too....